# PHP postgresql pg_copy_from

Tags: php, postgresql

I have about 200k rows to import into Postgresql database. I found that I should use `pg_copy_from` function. I tried it, but it should return `true` or `false` and it returns `null`. And of course, it doesn't insert anything into db.

```
pg_copy_from($this->connection, $table, $data);
```

I also tried alternative pg_put_line

```
    pg_query($this->connection, "copy $table from stdin");
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        pg_put_line($this->connection, implode('\t', $row));
    }
    pg_put_line($this->connection, "\\.\n");
    pg_end_copy($this->connection);
```

It didn't help. It doesn't throw any error and I have no idea what is the problem. Do you have any idea why it returns `null` or how to solve this problem?

EDIT: 
my row looks like this

```
2019-04-01\t8\t3\tH\tA\t0021\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t15\t\\N\t0\t0\t0\t0
```

and I have 16 columns ... I can insert the same data using pdo query

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your data? Do you have a sample of the $data array? Just the layout and first data row should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use PostgreSQL tools and not PHP, because it seems to me your main goal is "I have about 200k rows to import into Postgresql database." and not the PHP pg_copy_from() function...

So, my suggestion, run a `pg_dump` command on terminal and then import your data also on terminal, using the `psql` command. Examples:

```
$ pg_dump -U postgres -f mydump.sql -t mytable mydatabase
```

Then to import run:

```
$psql -U postgres mydatabase < mydump.sql
```

---

Eventually, we come across a PHP function with weird behavior, I remember one time I was trying to use the pg_insert() function I believe with wildcards (? or $ I'm not sure right now) and it didn't work, so I gave up and used the pg_query() function instead. Maybe you have a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use PHP code to get the data, so it's preferable to stay in PHP. I found out there is `pg_last_error()` and debugged it. You were right it was a problem with the format. I changed the delimiter to `|` and it works!